# Explode on semicolons, isolate first word of each element, then implode

Tags: php, arrays, csv, split, substring

I have a string of values that are trailed by carets and groups of words are separated by semicolons.

I tried to split the string on semicolons, but I only want the first word after each semicolon without its trailing caret.

```
$myString = "apple^;ball^room^mouse^bat^;cricket^news^man^";
$myArray = explode(';', $myString);
print_r($myArray);
```

I want output from above string as below in single variable:

```
apple ball cricket
```

means first character befor caret sign of each semicolon

Answer (score 0):

With the use of some PHP string and array manipulation functions you can do this

```
$myString = "apple^;ball^room^mouse^bat^;cricket^news^man^";
$myArray = explode(';', $myString);

foreach ($myArray as &$a) {
    $p = strpos($a, '^');
    $a = substr($a,0,$p);
}
$str = implode(' ', $myArray);

echo 'Input was > ' . $myString . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Output is > ' . $str . PHP_EOL;
```

RESULT

```
Input was > apple^;ball^room^mouse^bat^;cricket^news^man^
Output is > apple ball cricket
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your string from every `^` character until the next occurring `;` (or the end of the string).  `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY()` will ensure that no empty elements are generated while exploding.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VtbB5))

```
$myString = "apple^;ball^room^mouse^bat^;cricket^news^man^";

var_export(implode(' ', preg_split('/\^[^;]*;?/', $myString, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)));
```

Output:

```
'apple ball cricket'
```